# Discord bot: Why does this code not find any users in the channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

It does not log any errors, it just does not find any users. I ran the code and but the log I asked for.
There are users present.

```
import discord

# Create a new set of intents and enable the voice_states intent
intents = discord.Intents.none()
intents.voice_states = True
intents.reactions = True

# Create the Discord client with the new intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

voice_client = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # Get the guild that the bot is connected to
    guild = client.guilds[0]

    # Check if there are any users in voice channels
    members = [
        member
        for channel in guild.voice_channels
        for member in channel.members
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to enable the member intents.

```py
intents.members = True
```